# this.props.persistor.subscribe is not a function Redux persist

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, redux, persistence

I am trying to persist and rehydrate my redux immutable.js stores but unfortunately I am receiving this error `this.props.persistor.subscribe is not a function`. I think I am exporting my store correctly, it works without the persistence, however when adding persistence it results in the above error. Below is my `index.js`:

```
import React from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import configureStore from './store/configure-store';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';
import {persistStore} from 'redux-persist-immutable';
import {saveState} from "./actions/local-storage"
import {throttle} from 'lodash'
import {fromJS} from 'immutable'
import {PersistGate} from "redux-persist/es/integration/react"

const store = configureStore();
const persistor = persistStore(store);

render(
   <Provider store={store}>
     <PersistGate
       loading={() => console.log('looading')}
       persistor={persistor}>
      <App />
     </PersistGate>
   </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
registerServiceWorker();
```

and here is my `configure-store.js` where I am rehydrating:

```
import rootReducer from '../reducers'
import {
  createStore,
  compose,
  applyMiddleware
} from 'redux'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import { autoRehydrate } from 'redux-persist-immutable'
import {loadState} from "../actions/local-storage"

const persistedState = loadState()

export default (initialState) => createStore(
  rootReducer,
  initialState,
  autoRehydrate(),
  compose(
    applyMiddleware(thunk),
    window.devToolsExtension ? window.devToolsExtension() : f => f
  )
)
```

I have also tried the following with regards to this, in my index.js

```
store.subscribe(() => {
  var serializedState = JSON.stringify(store.getState());
  localStorage.setItem("state", serializedState);
});
render(
   <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
   </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)

etc...
```

and in my `configure-store.js`:

```
import rootReducer from '../reducers'
import {
  createStore,
  compose,
  applyMiddleware
} from 'redux'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import { autoRehydrate } from 'redux-persist-immutable'
import {loadState} from "../actions/local-storage"

export default (initialState) => {
  let persistedState

  if (localStorage.getItem("state")) {
    var serializedState = localStorage.getItem("state");
    /* upload changes to server here */
    persistedState = JSON.parse(serializedState);
  }

  createStore(
    rootReducer,
    persistedState,
    // autoRehydrate(),
    compose(
      applyMiddleware(thunk),
      // autoRehydrate(),
      window.devToolsExtension ? window.devToolsExtension() : f => f
    )
  )
}
```

I believe this should add the `state` to local storage and `rehydrate` the state back in to the web app. However, I receive the following error in relation to this `Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined`. I'm not really sure what's going wrong, this is my first experience with persistence, however I'm not really fussed how it is done either, whether that be through `redux-immutable-persist` or not.

Comment: @DaveDevidson, I too facing this issue now.Did you solved this?If yes,Please let me know.Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you ever find a fix for this?